# Get data from relational tables using entity framework C# WebApi

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using **Webapi** and i have two tables in database and Department and Info tables. Department table has relation with Info table. I am using entity framework to retrieve data from database but I am getting data from only one table INFO so the department table shows NULL it has to show department data because both have relation.

Without Webapi the code is working fine. So where I am wrong and why does not Department table show in webapi.

I hope you understand my question thanks.

**Contorller**

```
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult EmployeeList()
    {
       var List = DB.Infoes.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
       return Json(List);            
    }   
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class Info
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Image_Name { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_name { get; set; }
    public string Desription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeprtmentIDFK { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public partial class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Info> Infoes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have to include it: `DB.Infoes.Include(info => info.Department).ToList()`

Comment: showing this error ..... cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: you need to reference this namespace: `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: as a side comment, List is not a good choice  for a variable name for obvious reasons. Something like list or infoes would work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

As it is discussed [here](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include), in order to fetch navigation properties you have to `Include` them in your IQueryable, otherwise you always get null values.